# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: Xcode 6.0.1

Tags: ios, xcode, architecture, undefined-symbol

I'm getting the following errors, when I try to compile my Xcode project.
How do I add these class' to my compile sources in Xcode 6.0.1?

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTColor",
>   referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in PieChartViewController.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTFill", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in PieChartViewController.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTGradient", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in PieChartViewController.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTGraphHostingView", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in PieChartViewController.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTLegend", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in PieChartViewController.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTLineStyle", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in PieChartViewController.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTMutableTextStyle", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in PieChartViewController.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTPieChart", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in PieChartViewController.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTTextLayer", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in PieChartViewController.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTTheme", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in PieChartViewController.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CPTXYGraph", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in PieChartViewController.o   "_kCPTPlainWhiteTheme", referenced from:

Comment: Did you update Xcode recently? If so, clean your build folder and delete the derived data. Then build your project again.

Comment: I've tried that, but I'm still getting the above errors.

Comment: i think you using some third party library and u missing those classes please make sure you have all necessary classes in your project

Comment: This is a linker error, not a compiler error. It states that some libraries are missing. Did you add all the required frameworks to your project?

Comment: Yup, there're all in the frameworks folder.

Comment: If you aren't compiling the frameworks from source:  Are you sure those frameworks support x86_64?